# OpenGL program keeps crashing?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, core-graphics, glfw

This code returns 3 errors (literally all the errors)
`GLEW init failed; GLFW init failed; Window creation failed`:

```cpp
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#include <iostream>


//Window dimensions
const GLint SCREEN_WIDTH = 800, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;


int main() {
    //Initialize GLFW
    if (glfwInit() != GLEW_OK) { 
        std::cout << "GLFW init failed\n"; 
        glfwTerminate(); 
    }


    //Setup GLFW window properties
    //OpenGL version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); //Large version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); //Small version 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //Detects any old OpenGL code, this will throw an error
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); //Allows forward compatibility (between differnt OS) 


    //Creating window
    GLFWwindow* window; 
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "OpenGL Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "GLFW window creation failed!\n";
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    //Get buffer size information
    int BUFFER_WIDTH, BUFFER_HEIGHT;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &BUFFER_WIDTH, &BUFFER_HEIGHT);

    //Set context for GLEW to use (can change between which window)
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //Allow modern extension features
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;


    if (glfwInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "Glew init failed!\n";
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
    }


    //Setup viewport size
    glViewport(0, 0, BUFFER_WIDTH, BUFFER_HEIGHT);



    //Main game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        //Get + Handle user input events
        glfwPollEvents();

        //Clear window
        glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only error of relevance is the `glfwInit();` call, since you failed to exit your application once that error appears.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry? "...failed to exit your application once that error appears"? What do you mean by that? I did `glfwTerminate();` for both events.

Comment: No, a C++ `main` function has not returned.  Your code calls `glfwTerminate()`, but that has nothing to do with `main` returning -- it is just a function call.  To terminate an application, you either `return` from `main`, or you call `exit()`.  That's why you see the other error messages -- you failed to bail out on the first error and your program kept going.  Also, think logically about it -- what if I want to end the gl engine in the middle of my application, but keep my app going?  Will glfwTerminate() end my entire application?  Of course not.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

> ```cpp
> if (glfwInit() != GLEW_OK) { 
>    std::cout << "GLFW init failed\n"; 
>    glfwTerminate();
> }
> ```

`GLEW_OK` is defined as 0 (See https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/blob/master/auto/src/glew_tail.h)

So this is evaluated as follows:
`if (glfwInit() != 0)` which will only be true if GLFW did initialize properly.

So change that part to:

```
if (glfwInit() == 0) { 
    std::cout << "GLFW init failed\n"; 
    glfwTerminate(); 
}
```

Comment: I think OP meant `glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE` and just used the wrong constant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , you need to initialize Glew.

```
GLenum GlewInitResult;
GlewInitResult = glewInit();
if ( GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult) 
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues.

[`glfwInit`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#ga317aac130a235ab08c6db0834907d85e) returns `GLFW_TRUE` if it succeeds (`GLFW_TRUE` is 1). So it has to be:

```cpp
if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE) { 
    std::cout << "GLFW init failed\n"; 
}
```

(Note, if [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/)  failed to initialize, then there is no need to call `glfwTerminate()`)

If you want to install [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), then you've to call `glewInit` rather than `glfwInit`. `glewInit` returns `GLEW_OK`, if it succeeds (see [Initializing GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)). `GLEW_OK` is 0. So it has to be:

```cpp
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {

    std::cout << "Glew init failed!\n";
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```